# Кастомный вид для элементов ListView

Tags: android

Господа, вопрос таков, как мне сделать такой же стиль сообщений? 
Ну то есть с тенью, и таким выводом времени, и стрелочкой сбоку.

Никак не могу понять, как они так сделали. Смотрел исходный код телеграма (там тоже подобный вид сообщений), так там вообще заново рисуется это, и никаких стилей нету, но я думаю можно ведь все это сделать без новой рисовки. Прощу Вас, помочь мне.

Спасибо
[image: WhatsApp]

Comment: Что значит "без новой рисовки" ? где эта ваша "старая рисовка" ? Скорее всего это `ListView` с кастомным айтемом: два текстовых поля и ода картинка (галочки), прямоугольник а котором все это написано - подложка (background) - он может быть вообще любым, какой нарисовать фантазии хватит

Comment: Класс. Я это и понял, меня интересует сама подложка, стиль, то есть с тенями. Такой же стиль как в мессенджере, я реализовать не смог

Comment: Это нарисовано. Просто картинка прямоугольника с тенью - никаких стилей тут выдумывать не надо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сделать такой айтем (элемент списка) нам нужно проделать следующие действия:

1. Подготовить подложку (backgr.9.png) - это картинка 9patch, то есть растягивающаяся под размер контента. Помещаем ее в `res/drawable/`.
   Я не художник, но выглядит это примерно так:
   [image: backgr.9.png]
2. Подготовить изображение-галочку (check.png), она должа быть сделана под все необходимые разрешения, помещаем их соответственно в `res/drawable-hdpi/` , `res/drawable-xhdpi/` и тд. Вот, к примеру, для `hdpi`:   [image: check.png]
3. Подготавливаем разметку (item.xml) , размещаем элементы , как нам необходимо:

.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/backgr">

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Некоторое сообщение"
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="12dp" />

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="19:15"
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/check"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Получаем такой результат:

[image: Результат]

Возможно потребуется нарисовать отдельные подложки для нажатого состояния, выделенного и тд. , тогда в качестве background к элементу используем селектор (background.xml), а не отдельную картинку и помещаем ее в `res/drawable/` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/backgr_pressed" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/backgr_pressed"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/backgr"/>
 </selector>
```

Тогда разметка (item.xml) будет начинаться так:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    ....
```

Для того, чтобы использовать несколько разных видов айтемов в одном списке ( как например приходящие и исходящие сообщения ), нужно подготовить аналогично и другие виды, затем реализовать кастомный адаптер для наполнения списка и в нем переопределить метод `getItemViewType()` , который будет отображать нужный вид в зависимости от определенных условий. Реализация этого механизма выходит за рамки данного вопроса.